# Zabbix 6.0 иероглифы zabbix_get

Tags: zabbix

Команда **zabbix_get** на сервере **Zabbix** возвращает иероглифы.
Например:

```
root@zabbix:/# zabbix_get -s 192.168.5.18 -k system.run["ipconfig"]

▒▒▒▒ன▒▒ ▒▒⮪▒▒▒ IP ▒▒▒ Windows

▒▒▒▒▒▒ Ethernet Ethernet:

   DNS-▒▒▒䨪▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒祭▒▒ . . . . . :
   IPv4-▒▒▒▒. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.18
   ▒▒᪠ ▒▒▒▒▒ . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   ▒᭮▒▒▒▒ ▒▒. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.5.1

▒㭭▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒ isatap.{315490EA-E5FA-4E28-A1C5-4D4243B12098}:

   ▒▒▒▒ﭨ▒ ▒।▒. . . . . . . . : ▒।▒ ▒▒।▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒㯭▒.
   DNS-▒▒▒䨪▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒祭▒▒ . . . . . :
root@zabbix:/#
```

192.168.5.18 - компьютер с ОС Windows 10. Подскажите как это можно исправить, спасибо.

**Дополнение!**
На **192.168.5.18** в cmd выставил кодировку **65001** (шрифт "Lucida Console"). Это **UTF-8**. А на Zabbix сервере команда "**zabbix_get -s 192.168.5.18 -k system.run["chcp"]**" сообщает, что кодировка **866**. Почему так?

Comment: [chcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp)? (1251 или utf8)

Comment: На 192.168.5.18 chcp 866. На нем надо переделать в utf8 получается?

Comment: или на нем или у вас в терминале, или конвертируйте

Comment: На zabbix (linux ubuntu 20.04) добавил все локали ru_RU и поочередно выбирал их по умолчанию. Иероглифы в консоли Linux не менялись. На 192.168.5.18 выставил chcp 850. Вывод команды ipconfig на нем на английском языке. Выставил на Zabbix по умолчанию en_US.UTF-8, но всё равно иероглифы.

Comment: Выставил на 192.168.5.18 chcp 65001 (шрифт "Lucida Console"). Это UTF-8. А на сервере Zabbix по умолчанию en_US.UTF-8. Тоже не помогло, иероглифы даже не меняются...

Answer (score 0):

Ура! Я решил проблему. Нашел ответ на англоязычной версии данного форума:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window

> Начиная (по крайней мере) с Windows 10 версии 1903 у вас есть возможность установить языковой стандарт системы ( язык для программ, не поддерживающих Unicode ) на UTF-8 , но на момент написания этой статьи эта функция все еще находится в стадии бета -тестирования .

Answer (score 0):

Я дополню вашу проблему своей и готовым решением.

Моя проблема: win server 2012, В конструкции "zabbix.exe->cmd.exe->Powershell.exe" cmd почему-то работала с кодировкой UTF-16LE и в мониторинге zabbix вместо кириллицы были знаки вопроса????, когда, как powershell точно всё делал в UTF-8.

В итоге, я переделал в конфиге строку 1 в строку 2 (добавил "@chcp 65001>nul &&"):

1. UserParameter=get.gost-pcidss.csv, powershell.exe -encodedCommand Yw....
2. UserParameter=get.gost-pcidss.csv,@chcp 65001>nul && powershell.exe -encodedCommand Yw....

И, разумеется, в закодированной команде скрипт начинался с текста "chcp 65001;"
Надеюсь кому-то помог.